# How can I run code that only has async APIs without deadlocking in an environment where I know the Thread Pool will be saturated?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, biztalk

I am trying to write helper methods for calling from BizTalk. BizTalk doesn't understand Tasks or async/await, so the helper methods must return a normal .NET return type not lifted into a `Task<T>`.

The helper methods use the [IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) library and subsequently [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) to make a call out to an HTTP-based API and then cache this result. These classes only have an asynchronous API i.e. all the methods that do the work return `Task<T>` and end with -Async.

The way that BizTalk manages its thread pool essentially guarantees that the thread pool will be saturated (at a default of 25 worker threads) if it there is a high message load; for example a large number of files have been dropped at once - this is a feasible scenario in normal usage and not actually a problem. I have observed this through debugging.

When the helper code makes an API call, this is quite expensive as it returns a lot of data, and I only want one call to be in progress at a time. If all the implementation was synchronous I would just use a `lock` statement around the cache refresh, as the delay in processing messages is acceptable for the sake of ensuring synchronisation. Locking has been shown to deadlock, which makes sense to me, as the application architecture essentially guarantees that no threads will be available to complete the asynchronous methods. This is a more extreme case of the commonly-given advice of not locking in the context of asynchronous code, in that it is not just likely but certain to deadlock.

I've tried using `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` to do the equivalent to locking but in a non-blocking fashion i.e. still prevent more than one thread from entering the block, but by making them yield instead of blocking. This doesn't solve the problem, as the top-level helper methods must still block to wait for the cache update to complete. My hypothesis is that the moment this wait yields the thread, it then gets swallowed up processing a new message - which then blocks it, preventing the thread which entered the semaphore from continuing.

The following **pseudocode** (i.e. please don't try and correct me on coding style issues irrelevant to the problem. It also can't be an MCVE unless you have an installation of BizTalk handy) illustrates the problem I am trying to solve:

```
public class Helper
{
    public static string GetCachedValue(string key)
    {
        // need to wait until the cache is updated, but blocking here makes all worker threads unavailable
        CacheData().Wait();

        return _cache.GetValue(key);
    }

    private static DateTime _lastRead;

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim throttle = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    private static async Task CacheData()
    {
        try{
            // stop more than one thread from entering this block at a time
            await throttle.WaitAsync();

            if(_lastRead < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
            {
                var context = new AuthenticationContext(/* uninteresting parameters*/); 
                var token = await context.GetTokenAsync();

                // can't use HttpClientFactory here because the .NET 4.5.2 implementation doesn't supply any way of setting the web proxy
                var client = new HttpClient();

                var data =  await client.GetAsync("api/Data");

                // unimportant cache update code

                _lastRead = DateTime.Now;

            }
        }
        finally 
        {
            throttle.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

- Is my understanding of what the fundamental problem is here correct?
- How do I solve it?

Comment: "Async all the way" is not an option, I guess?

Comment: @Fildor nope, not as far as I am aware. As I mentioned the public method to be called into cannot be async because the caller doesn't know how to unpack that Task into its result implicitly like the C# compiler does, and never will.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is actually "how do I do sync-over-async when the thread pool is saturated", and the only real answer is "you can't". The problem with sync-over-async is that it blocks a thread and then might require *another* thread to unblock that one.

One thing you can try is to install your own context (temporarily) on your thread. I have an `AsyncContext` type in my [AsyncEx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) that can do this. So at your BizTalk entry point, you could use that instead of blocking directly:

```
// Old code:
//   var result = MyLogicAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var result = AsyncContext.Run(() => MyLogicAsync());
```

This will allow `await` continuations to run on your own thread by default. It kind of behaves similar to a UI message loop (just without UI).

Unfortunately, you can't guarantee that this will always work, because the continuations only capture that context *by default*. And for general-purpose libraries like `ActiveDirectory` and `HttpClient`, capturing context is considered bad practice; most library code goes out of its way to use the thread pool by always using `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

So, the only way to avoid deadlocks in sync-over-async code is to ensure the thread pool is not saturated. If there was some way to limit BizTalk to some value and have the thread pool larger than that, then that would work.

A much more ideal solution would be to go "sync all the way". You'd want to replace `HttpClient` with `WebClient`, but from your description it sounds like `ActiveDirectory` doesn't support sync APIs.

You might get away with a hybrid solution: use `WebClient` to make the API call synchronous, and wrap all `ActiveDirectory` calls in `AsyncContext.Run`. I'm thinking this *might* work because the ASP.NET Core team has removed most/all `ConfigureAwait(false)` calls in their code. So the HTTP API would be synchronous, and the `ActiveDirectory` would be asynchronous but with its continuations running in the thread that is waiting for it (not requiring a thread pool thread).

But even if you get this working, it's not guaranteed in the future. Missing `ConfigureAwait(false)` can be considered a "bug", and if they "fix" the bug by adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` back in, then your code would be subject to deadlocks again.

The only truly guaranteed solution would be to force the asynchronous APIs to be synchronous, by writing your own proxy WebAPI that wraps the `ActiveDirectory` calls. Then your BizTalk code would talk to that API (and the other API) using `WebClient`, and all the BizTalk code would be synchronous at that point.

Comment: Thank you! This pretty much confirms what I suspected but didn't want to accept. The only remaining hazy idea for me is whether my understanding of BizTalk's thread management is accurate, so anyone reading this - don't take my word for it. The necessity of using hacks to make this work (reliably?!) is enough of a justification to rewrite with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say first, it looks like you just creating a lot of unnecessary problems by trying to do all this fancy stuff in a helper class.  Because A) there's really no practical case for async operations in a helper class as it's not going to change message processing time, B) *you should **not** be calling http endpoints in a helper class*.

So, the correct solution is to call the http endpoint using an **Ordered Delivery Send Port**.

I say Ordered Delivery because of this: "and I only want one call to be in progress at a time", but...it really doesn't matter what you *want*, you should do serial calls only if the service requires it or has capacity issues.

If you want to internally cache the results, there are many examples of this such as this here (all .Net rules apply): [Implement Caching for your BizTalk applications using "static" classes and methods](https://blogs.biztalk360.com/implement-caching-for-your-biztalk-applications-using-static-classes-and-methods/)

Comment: I agree with you and would rather not do it this way, but it's not my decision. Unfortunately this does not answer the question.

Comment: @TomW Then how can we help you demonstrate that whoever is making this decision is wrong?  Seems they don't understand how BizTalk or async in .Net works.  And yes, it does 100% answer the question because you should not be using this pattern in BizTalk.

Comment: My view is that the fact that this is BizTalk, and the fact that the slow work is an API request, is inconsequential and the meat of the question is the bridging of async with synchronous method calls. I think it should be possible to make the synchronisation work, the exact scenario is not that important. I added this detail because if it were absent someone would complain, not because I think it is material to the problem.

Comment: @TomW Well, yes, what you want to do is very, very basic and very, very, very common and BizTalk, as a platform, provides methods, patterns and features to do just this.  You're choosing to do something completely unnecessary and, on BizTalk, wrong.  Sorry.  It's like trying to use ADO to connect to Oracle in a SQL Server Stored Procedure...you can, but it's just...wrong.  Good luck, but you're trying to solve a problem you, or your 'architect' have created.

Comment: Johns is right, If you are having to call a helper class from BizTalk to talk to a web service then you are doing it wrong.   You will lose all the built in capabilities of BizTalk such as error handling, automatic retries, persistence & multi-threading.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf agreed. But that is not the question I asked.

Comment: where have you been?! no activity since july 1 !

Answer (score 0):

If the number of threads is the primary issue, you can reduce or increase the number of threads by adding the address and maxconnection setting to the connectionMangement section of the BTSNTSvc64.exe.config or BTSNTSvc.exe.config file if it is 32 bit.  Or as Johns said in his answer, if you want it single threaded, tick Ordered delivery on the Send Port.

```
    <system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
            <add address="*" maxconnection="25"   />

            <add address="https://LIMITEDSERVER.com*" maxconnection="5"  />
            <add address="https://GRUNTYSERVER.com*" maxconnection="50"  />
       </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
```

If you want it Async then you need to have a one way send port in BizTalk talking to your target system, and a Receive Location in BizTalk that the other system can send the response to.